# Does Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization make things quicker?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Does calculation become quicker when I use Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization instead of normally solving the equation $$A^TAx = A^Tb? $$ Since $$Q^TQ =I$$ That eliminates the need to calculate the Inverse of A'A  , but what about the time it takes to convert the matrix into the form A = QR and then solving for the rest of the equation? I'm working on a 100,000 x 12 matrix and I'm noticing 
**WITHOUT GRAM SCHMIDT IT TOOK   0.03126811981201172**

***WITH GRAM SCHMIDT IT TOOK   0.0937509536743164***

I'm not sure if this should be happening. The solution seems to be correct so my code looks okay. This is what I did
$$ x = inv(A^TA)A^Tb$$
After A = QR $$ x  = inv(R)Q^Tb$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say that calculating $A=QR$ takes more time than just $A^TA$. Calculating $x$ from $A^TAx =A^Tb$ should be as fast as calculating it from $Rx = Q^Tb$.

Comment: Also, if you are coding this, never use `inv` to calculate the inverse of a matrix directly, unless you really need it. Solving a linear system is MUCH faster than calculating an inverse matrix!

Comment: What did you actually do to solve the normal equations, Matlab's backslash? inv and matrix multiplication? In any case, a QR takes about as long to get as any other direct method for solving a linear system. After you have it, like an LU decomposition it is quite cheap to solve the system in the end. The bigger advantage to QR is numerical stability: errors in the normal equation approach are *necessarily* amplified by a factor of at least cond(A)^2 while errors in the QR approach can be amplified by merely cond(A) if you use Householder or modified Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: The reasonable comparison in Matlab would be to do [Q,R]=qr(A); x=R\\(Q'*b); vs. x=(A'*A)\\(A'*b). You might further compare these to A\b which will already do least squares using whatever method Matlab internally chooses. I would expect the latter to be fastest.

Comment: @Ian I was actually solving this in Python, the code looks kinda messy. I didn't know that using the '\' in MATLAB is equivalent to solving the equations via back substitution. It makes much more sense since R is already triangular. Thanks!

Comment: @Wauzl Got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spend time building matrices $Q$ and $R$, but in the end you still need to invert a matrix.

Without any additional information (for example, that $R^{-1}$ is much easier to find than $(A^TA)^{-1}$), in your second approach you are paying the price of both orthogonalisation *and* inversion instead of just one inversion, hence the loss of performance.